# How do I check to see if a string is within an array in Visual Basic? How to write return statement for each function?

Tags: arrays, function, return, boolean, return-value

```
Module Main
Friend blnLoggedIn As Boolean
Dim arrUsernames() As String = {"Admin, Clerk, Manager"}
Dim arrPasswords() As String = {"P@ssword, pa$$word, and passw0rd"}

Sub Login(username As String, password As String)
    blnLoggedIn = False
    If VerifyUsername(username) And VerifyPassword(password) Then
        'Find index for username
        Dim userIndex As Integer
        For loopIndex = 0 To arrUsernames.Length - 1
            If arrUsernames(loopIndex) = username Then
                userIndex = loopIndex
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'Check for password match
        If arrPasswords(userIndex) = password Then
            blnLoggedIn = True
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(“Incorrect password.”)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Function VerifyUsername(username As String) As Boolean

    'If the username is found, Return True, otherwise Return False
End Function
Function VerifyPassword(password As String) As Boolean

    'If the passwords match, Return True, otherwise Return False
End Function

End Module
```

My instructions say:

Using what you know about search arrays, implement the VerifyUsername and VerifyPassword functions. They should return true if the username or password is found in the arrUsernames or arrPasswords array, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for homework help, but you need to tell us what you're having trouble with and what you've tried. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I have tried different if..Else statements, Statements using Contains and For loop statements. But I keep getting the same errors saying that a return statement is missing from all code paths??